# How to pass multiple text field's updated value in the same row to controller using hyperlink?

Tags: html, hyperlink, textbox, html-table

I have one jsp page in which I am showing some records in table in the jsp. In this table (the jsp) every row has 1 column where I have put the 'Edit' hyperlink. If I am updating value in the text fields in the same table. Then after clicking on that link, I want to get updated text field's value in my controller. 
Can any one tell me how to achieve this goal?

```
<table border="2">
<tr>
    <th>Student Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Contact No.</th>
    <th>Click here to edit</th>
    <th>Click here to save</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="currentStudent">
<%!int count = 0; %>
<tr>
    <td> 
        <input name = "sid" type="text" value= "${currentStudent.studentId}" size="10" />
    </td>
    <td>  
        <input id = "fn<%= count%>" name = "fn" type="text" value= "${currentStudent.firstName}" size="10"/>
    </td>   
    <td> 
        <input id = "ln<%= count%>" name = "ln" type="text" value= "${currentStudent.lastName}" size="10"/> 
    </td>
    <td>  
        <input id = "age<%= count%>" name = "age" type="text" value= "${currentStudent.age}" size="10"/>
    </td>    
    <td>
        <input id = "mno<%= count%>" name = "mno" type="text" value= "${currentStudent.mobileNo}" size="10"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input name = "edit" type="button" value= "Edit" size="100" onclick="enableFields"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a id = "link" href="modifystudent?sid=${currentStudent.studentId}&fn=_&ln=_&age=_mno">Save</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<%count++; %>
</c:forEach>
</table>`
```

I have put _ where i need to insert the logic for getting the value of same row's text field's.

Can any one suggest any logic?

Comment: Please consider selecting your code and formatting it by pressing Ctrl + K.

Comment: i did.any suggestions regarding asked ques. ?

Comment: Nope, you didn't. You will have more chances to have your question answered if you present it nice and clear.

Comment: Can any one attempt to answer the ques mentioned above ?